# ошибка перевода во всплывающей подсказке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

на странице «[проверка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review)» (возможно, и в других местах) при наведении курсора на аватар пользователя открывается всплыващая подсказка с информацией об этом пользователе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

среди этой информации присутствует надпись

```
активно n минут назад
```

мне кажется, более правильно (с точки зрения как русского языка, так и «американской политкорректности»), заменить слово «активно» на «активность»:

```
активность n минут назад
```

---

p.s. если интересно, как я добавил на картинку красивую тень: с помощью *imagemagick* по [*этому совету*](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#shadow): `$ convert -page +4+4 исходный.png -alpha set \( +clone -background navy -shadow 60x4+4+4 \) +swap -background none -mosaic с.тенью.png`

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, внес изменения в перевод.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, спасибо и за первое и за второе!

Comment: Вот буквально недавно переводил про эту тень. Она нужна для выделения скриншотов в сообщениях об ошибках. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-norepro/info Может, напишете краткую инструкцию для меты, чтобы на нее дать ссылку?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, написать инструкцию несложно, но там же и про *gui* что-нибудь должно быть. а я в этом деле — полный профан.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: в смысле «как добавить тень в фотошопе»? Да ну его. Только командная строка, только хардкор.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если не срочно нужно, то сделаю.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: да какая тут срочность. Мета вроде не переполняется, модераторы не стонут )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/745/#comment2142_745) от [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky):

Спасибо за замечание, внес изменения в перевод.